# Callback function syntax - why is this not allowed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

`function callbackFn(res){console.log(res)}`

I can write
`$.get("./a", function(response) {callbackFn(response)});`

Why can't I write
`$.get("./a", callbackFn(response));`

Comment: Because you're not passing a function to `$.get`. You're calling it immediately, and passing its return value, which is `undefined` in your case.

Comment: A shorter way would be `$.get("./a", callbackFn);`. Now you're passing your `callbackFn`, and it will get as arguments whatever `$.get` passes to it. There may be some extra arguments you're not using, but that's OK.

Comment: Shorter still would be `$.get("./a", console.log);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) are values in javascript, special objects is you will.

When you define a function like

```js
function callbackFn(res) {
  console.log(res)
}
```

`callbackFn`  references the function itself and `callbackFn()` *executes* or *call* the function and you get the value that this function returns.

The method you are showing is expecting an `string` as the first parameter and a `function` as the second.

So if you do:

```js
$.get("./a", callbackFn(response));
```

You are passing to `$.get` the return value of calling the function with the argument `response` (ie. callbackFn(response)).

To make it clearer, this is how a method like this is defined (this is an example, not the actual implementation)

```js
function get(path, callback) {
  fetch(path).then(function (response) {
    callback(response)
  })
}
```

As you can see, inside `get`, it's calling the function that is expected as a second parameter with the argument response (your callbackFn).

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the function *reference* to `$.get()`

```
$.get("./a", callbackFn)
```

Demo

```js
function handleResponse(data) {
  console.log('response data:\n', data);
}

$.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', handleResponse)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The second version calls `callbackFn()` immediately, and uses its return value as the second argument to `$.get()`. It's equivalent to

```
var temp = callbackFn(response):
$.get("./a", temp);
```

You need to wrap it in an anonymous function so that it won't be called immediately, but instead when `$.get` completes the AJAX request.